# A definite integral contianing ln(x)

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

everyone, I met a tough definite integral as follows,
$$I = \int\limits_1^\infty {\frac{{\ln x}}{{{{\left( {x + a} \right)}^m}{{\left( {x + b} \right)}^{n + 1}}}}} dx,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constant, $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: There's no $c$ and $d$, do you mean $m, n$?

Comment: I think partial fraction decomposition of the integrand might help. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas. Are you sure that we could do it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Nope, that's why I said, "I'm not sure though."

Comment: @PrasunBiswas. Sorry for that ! I misread the last part of your comment. Cheers :-(

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, No worries. :)

Comment: i'm sorry for the mistake, $c$ and $d$ are $m$ and $n$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If $~m,n\in\mathbb N,~$ then our integral can be expressed in terms of $~J^{(m-1,~n)}(a,b),~$ where $J(a,b)=$

$$=\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(x+a)(x+b)}~dx~=~\int_0^\infty-\int_0^1~=~\frac{\dfrac{\ln^2a-\ln^2b}2+\text{Li}_2\bigg(-\dfrac1a\bigg)-\text{Li}_2\bigg(-\dfrac1b\bigg)}{a-b},$$

see [dilogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function) $($ or **Spence's function** $)$ and [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.

Comment: Hi, dear Lucian, I tried it but I can’t get your results. Could you please show me in a more detail way? Here is my derivation:

Comment: $$J\left( {c,d} \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty  {}  - \int\limits_0^1 {}  = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\ln y}}{{\left( {y + c} \right)\left( {y + d} \right)}}dy}  + \frac{1}{{c - d}}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {\frac{1}{{y + c}} - \frac{1}{{y + d}}} \right)\ln ydy} $$

Comment: $$ = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\ln y}}{{\left( {y + c} \right)\left( {y + d} \right)}}dy}  + \frac{1}{{c - d}}\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\ln y}}{{y + c}}dy}  - \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\ln y}}{{y + d}}dy} } \right)$$

Comment: $$ = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\ln y}}{{\left( {y + c} \right)\left( {y + d} \right)}}dy}  + \frac{1}{{c - d}}\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\ln y}}{{\frac{y}{c} + 1}}d\frac{y}{c}}  - \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\ln y}}{{\frac{y}{d} + 1}}d\frac{y}{d}} } \right)$$

Comment: where ${\text{L}}{{\text{i}}_2}\left( z \right) =  - \int\limits_0^z {\frac{{\ln \left( {1 - u} \right)}}{u}du} $

Comment: @ChaoQT: I did not arrive at the afore-mentioned result by using high-school level methods of integration.

Comment: @ChaoQT: Basically, after decomposing the integrand into partial fractions, I used $\ln x~=~\bigg[\dfrac d{dk}~x^k\bigg]_{k=0}$ in conjunction with $x=ct$ $($or $x=dt)$ and $u=\dfrac1{1+t}$ in order to arrive at the well-known integral expression for the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), then I employed Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to simplify the result, which I then differentiated with regard to *k*, and evaluated it for $k\to0$.

Comment: Dear Lucian, could you send me the detailed derivation process of what you have described in your last response? Moreover, Could you also show me the relationship between ${J^{\left( {m - 1,n} \right)}}\left( {a,b} \right)$ and $J\left( {a,b} \right)$, please?